# Problems with variable in recursive programming in javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, recursion

I played around with some recursive programming. I have one variable to keep track of my depth (d). The console log is for me to see where the program is at the moment.

```js
var Test = function(){
 this.rekursiv = function(d){
  this.d = d;
  console.log("case 1 granted, d: " + this.d);  
  if( this.d < 3) {
  console.log("going deeper..");
  this.rekursiv(this.d + 1);
  console.log("going back..");  
  }
  console.log("d: " + this.d  );
  }
} 
t = new Test();
t.rekursiv(0);
```

Here is my problem:
Whenever I go one level deeper, I pass "this.d + 1" to the next level.
Howevever, debugging the code (with the console.log) shows that d doesn't only get changed in one level/depth, but in every level/depth.

Why is this so? How can i prevent the code from doing this?

Comment: `this.d` isn't a variable. It's a property on an object, which happens to be the same object used as the value of `this` in the recursive call. There's no reason for a separate variable in your code, since you already have the `d` parameter.

Comment: You can write it like this: `function Test(d) { if (d < 3) { console.log(d); Test(d + 1); console.log(d) } else console.log("base case") }`. The problem with your function is, that it doesn't return anything. The base case just performs a side effect (`console.log`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the local variable `d`?

With `this.d`, you are setting a property of the instance of `Test`. And with the ending of `rekursiv`, you do not change the value back to the former value.

```js
var Test = function () {
        this.rekursiv = function(d) {
            console.log("case 1 granted, d: " + d);
            if (d < 3) {
                console.log("going deeper..");
                this.rekursiv(d + 1);
                console.log("going back..");  
            }
            console.log("d: " + d  );
        }
    },
    t = new Test;

t.rekursiv(0);
```

Another solution would be, to increase `this.d` at the start of the function `rekursiv`and decrease it at the end.

```js
var Test = function () {
        this.d = 0;
        this.rekursiv = function() {
            this.d++;
            console.log("case 1 granted, d: " + this.d);  
            if (this.d < 3) {
                console.log("going deeper..");
                this.rekursiv();
                console.log("going back..");  
            }
            console.log("d: " + this.d  );
            this.d--;
        }
    },
    t = new Test;

    t.rekursiv();
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line:

```
this.d = d;
```

Now, d is a local variable and no more instance  variable.

```js
var Test = function(){
  this.rekursiv = function(d){
    console.log("case 1 granted, d: " + d);
    if( d < 3) {
      console.log("going deeper..");
      this.rekursiv(d + 1);
      console.log("going back..");
    }
    console.log("d: " + d  );
  }
}
t = new Test();
t.rekursiv(0);
```

Comment: Actually declaring d again inside rekursiv function is not necessary. This line can be removed.

Comment: @MichałMłoźniak You are right, it is pointless to redeclare the same variable.